# Questions regarding language translation using .pot file

Tags: gettext, language-translation, po

I have a .pot file that I wish to translate to a native language and get the final .po file. At this moment, the only plausible option that I have is to open the set of .pot files in a text editor and convert each phrase to the native language.

I would like to know if this can be automated by using some tool/software . I tried POEDIT (in Windows) for converting my .pot file to the native language (Hindi) but it could not perform a single translation. Please provide some inputs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Translator Toolkit provided by Google.
https://translate.google.com/toolkit

(you need a Google account)

Before uploading your file you have to change the file extension to .po so google can accept it.

After translation; download the translated file and use your editor of choice to manage and optimize your translations.

Comment: this looks good thanks for your answer. Any chance of automating this whole process by some scripting. Please provide your inputs on this too.